# Error related to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, mstest, swi-prolog

I am developing a windows store app which take the user input(mathematical question),process it using prolog and output the answer. I have add Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll as an reference to my windows Store app.

I refer 
https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/contrib-swiplcs/blob/master/TestSwiPl/PlQuery.cs

This reference creates two errors,

1.Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Configuration.dll'

2.Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Configuration, version=2.0.0.0,..

Can I solve this error or Is it not possible to use this as a reference in windows store app. I'm using visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 3):

You should not reference the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` assembly from any production assemblies you're deploying. It should only be referenced from test projects.

Remove the reference and fix any build errors. Move unit tests into a unit test project if that's the root cause. Unit Tests should not be located inside a deployment item.

As for the `System.Configuration` reference, you likely want v4 not v2.

For this, remove the reference and add a correct reference to v4.

If the `System.Configuration` reference is not yours, but instead a binding from an assembly you are referencing, you likely need a binding redirect. For reference you may want to review [Redirecting Assembly Versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN.

HTH.