# Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Configuration AND Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Configuration.dll

Tags: win-universal-app

I am developing UWP App via VS2015 in Win10. My App was running perfect, but just today when I start running my App, even I didn't make changes of such ... and It shows 2 errors and is not running now.

```
1. Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.      

2. Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Configuration.dll'
```

What is these errors ... I didn't find the satisfactory solution

[image]

Comment: Look in the References section of the solution explorer wether any of the entries there show a yellow exclamation mark. If none do check wether System.Configuration.dll is listed there. In any case I'd first try to remove the faulty reference if it exists and just readd it.

Comment: @OliverUlm, The problem is ! there is no exclamation mark inside reference ... so this  was a bit confusing error ... I think its an internal error. So for this purpose I just created another blank project with the same name and just copied all folders and pages etc .. to the new one and then run that .. and it ran perfect.
By the way thanks for your interest.

Comment: happy to hear you have been able to fix it. If you still have the broken version around you could run a DIFF on the projects to see what might have caused it.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to resolve this by checking "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio" (the "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" was already checked), then rebuilding.  You can find these settings in Tools --> NuGet Package Manager -->  Package Manager Settings.

Comment: A very simple solution!

Comment: This alone didn't work for me. I first had to follow another answer which states, "**I fixed a similar problem by deleting the C:\Users\%username%.nuget directory."** Then I went back and followed your answer, and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed a similar problem by deleting the C:\Users\%username%.nuget directory.

Answer (score 3):

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227983/error-related-to-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-namespace), need to remove "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework"

Answer (score 2):

### UWP C# XAML App, MVS2017

I had a similar issue today, with the following error when building, after installing a new NUGET package (concretely NUGET package `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls`):

```
"cannot resolve assembly or windows metadata file 'type universe cannot resolve assembly: netstandard, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, …"
```

It turned out to be an **incompatibility between NUGET package versions**. I found out by fidgetting a bit in NUGET package manager with the package versions. A bit of trial and error, and I found out that by downgrading the version of the newly installed package, and upgrading the version of another package (in this case `NewtonSoft.Json`), I started building normally without errors or warnings...

Answer (score 2):

I had this error following updates in my nuget packages.

I resolved it by updating the `TargetPlatformMinVersion` (in my case it was from `10.0.17763.0` to `10.0.18362.0`).

Answer (score 1):

I turned this on
Tools --> NuGet Package Manager --> Package Manager Settings
Allow Nuget to download missing packages
Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio

But got a nuget error that there was a file lock

I had to fix it this way

1. cd to C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp
2. delete the NugetScratch folder

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this in a somewhat dated build script. It was a build that used one top-level SLN composed of multiple SLN files from numerous projects and efforts. I used to be able to just do,

`call nuget restore "%Top_Level_SLN_File%" -Recursive`

and trust all the packages were getting restored. Now I have to run,

`for /r %%I IN (*.sln) DO call nuget restore "%%~I" -Recursive`

It might have to do with the fact that a private nuget feed is being leveraged for some of the packages, but that might be a red herring. I haven't deep-dived the issue to get minimal repro steps.