# How to access data from SQL Server database in Win10 UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I want to read data from SQL server database in Win10 UWP. So I'm trying to run this sample codes from https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-access-data-from-935e360c
 in Visual Studio to read data from SQL server to UWP. I don't know why I keep getting this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCdTT.png)

I already read this and even tried the answers given :
[Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Configuration AND Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Configuration.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332437/type-universe-cannot-resolve-assembly-system-configuration-and-cannot-resolve-a)

Comment: Don't  paste code or errors as imagines, paste your code, what your a trying to do, what you expect to happen, an the actual error, also please read the help on asking a question

Comment: As far as I know, you can only achieve this using WCF services, because UWP doesn't allow you to connect directly to it. Another way is to use SQLite instead of MS SQL Server

Comment: @Ferus You are not correct. This is supported, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885735/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-a-windows-10-uwp-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to SQL server database from a Windows 10 UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885735/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-a-windows-10-uwp-app)

Comment: @Stefan Wick MSFT Thank you Stefan :), do you know if this is supported in Windows 10 enterprise? i think that it has not been updated with this.

Comment: Yes, it's supported in the win10 Enterprise sku.